html to Sharepoint aspx
I have a website created in html but now it needs to sit on a Sharepoint server. How do we make the HTML files work on a Sharepoint server?

You want to host your website on a SharePoint Server or within the SharePoint farm? It's not the same thing.

did you still need assistance on this subject?

A SharePoint Server, to be more precise a SharePoint server with Web Front-End (WFE) role is a Windows Server with Internet Information Service (IIS).
So you can use IIS to host your website by creating a new web application over your HTML folder. With this scenario you don't use SharePoint at all, only IIS.
References:

Relationship between app server and WFE server in sharepoint 3 tier and how data will flow between servers?
IIS Web Server Overview
SharePoint Integration with IIS

